# Why am I getting "Minified React error #31" after creating a new Gatsby project?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've tried installing **gatsby-cli** on my machine and created a new project, but after I generate it and try to serve it, I get `Minified React error #31`. These are the steps I've followed:

```
npm i -g gatsby-cli
```

And got many vulnerability issues I can't recover. I think it had to do with `hapi`. Then:

```
$ gatsby new my-project
$ cd my-project
$ gatsby serve
```

Then I get

```
failed We've encountered an error: Minified React error #31; visit
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=Error%3A%20ENOENT%3A%20no%20such%20file%20or%20directory%2C%20open%20'%
2FUsers%2Fwayoshi%2FDev%2Flegionhack-home%2F.cache%2Fmatch-paths.json'&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev
environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Would this be a known common error?

Here's my enviroment info:

```
macOS 10.14 Mojave
node v12.22
npm v7.21
```

Comment: It fails just with the starter or did you add some code? If so, please add it...

Comment: Seems this would be after adding some code, as I've created a third new project and `gatsby develop` ran perfectly without doing any edits on it. 

Comment: Then provide some code, with the information provided it's really difficult to guess what could possible go wrong :/

Comment: instead of `$ gatsby serve` use `$ gatsby develop` give a try it worked for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`gatsby develop` runs the development server. If you want to run a production build you need `gatsby build` to build the app and then `gatsby serve` to run the production build.